# How to use ternary operator on RadioGroup?

Tags: android

I would like to know can i use the following description?

```
int status_flameout = HardWareController.getInstance().gethardStatus(1);

status_flameout == 1 ? radioGroup_flameOut.check(R.id.radio1) : radioGroup_flameOut.check(R.id.radio0);
```